# Set the default highlighting mode to "lang-php"

Tags: feature-request, questions, highlighting-code

There are some questions for which the syntax highlighting is not active because none of the tags used for the question have syntax highlighting enabled.

- [Difficulties with the #ajax form item attribute](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/difficulties-with-the-ajax-form-item-attribute)
- [Show the value of a node-form field inside an AJAX field added via hook_form_alter()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/show-the-value-of-a-node-form-field-inside-an-ajax-field-added-via-hook-form-alte)
- [how to display the uploaded zip file content in drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4869/how-to-display-the-uploaded-zip-file-content-in-drupal)
- [How to use Devel module to see what creates an URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4885/how-to-use-devel-module-to-see-what-creates-an-url)

It is probably better to set PHP as default syntax highlighting mode, as in most of the questions, the shown code is PHP code; if the answer is showing code in a different programming language, it still possible to force the highlighter to use a different syntax mode, or set a different default highlighting mode for specific tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the better solution would be to set the default to auto-detect. It should work pretty well for PHP in this mode, and more importantly it won't completely wreck other languages (say, XML) that might commonly find their way into a question.

I'd argue that simply adding the [php] tag to such questions would be enough, but since the entire site is about Drupal (which sorta *implies* PHP), that just makes the [php] tag into a synonym for [drupal] (and therefore sorta useless).

Comment: I remember seeing "auto-detect" as option for the tag syntax highlighting, but I didn't think that could be also one of the options for the default syntax highlighting. If it work well with PHP, then it is a better option then explicitly setting the syntax highlighting to "lang-php." Probably most of the tags should be reset to "default" too; I set most of them to a specific syntax highlighting because the default is actually "none," and I didn't know how much trustable was "auto-detect."

Comment: Autodetect actually works reasonably well for most C-like languages, XML, HTML, etc... Well enough that if you expect languages to be *mixed* you'll want the associated tags to all be set to autodetect. That's probably less important *here* than it is on, say, SO, but probably still worth doing for some of the more tangential tags ([tag:ajax] would be a good candidate I suspect).

Comment: This is very useful information; thank you. If I knew it, I would have set the correct option; now there are probably some tags that would have their settings changed. `:-)`