# Enable code highlight in quotes by default

Tags: feature-request, highlighting-code

[This network-wide question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158293/language-hints-for-quoted-code) shows how to enable syntax highlight in code blocks inside quotes, as it's off by default. But here most of the time we want PHP highlight.

My request is: can Drupal Answers treat all posts as if having `<!-- language-all: default -->` unless explicitly set otherwise? Now apparently it's `none` for quotes, and [this answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/590/16495) was applied only outside quotes.